# Move 'n' row to become column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this sample dataframe,

```
      A       B       Date       C
0   83.04   82.70   01012019    0.0
1   83.04   82.71   01012019    3.0
2   83.02   82.70   02012019    0.0
3   83.02   82.69   02012019    5.0
4   82.98   82.67   03012019    2.0
5   81.28   79.61   03012019    3.0
```

When I use this code

```
output = combined.assign(Period=df.groupby('Date').cumcount()).pivot(index='Period', columns='Date',values=['A','B','C'])
```

I received a new dataframe with the wrong column header (I want date to be the column)

[image]

How am I able to swap the first row and second row so that the second row can be the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `MultiIndex` columns, so if you drop the highest level, you will get back your dataframe with only the `date` columns.

```
df['Period'] = df.groupby('Date').cumcount()

df_new = df.pivot_table(values=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns='Date', index='Period')
df_new.columns = [col[1] for col in df_new.columns]

    1012019 2012019 3012019 1012019 2012019 3012019 1012019 2012019 3012019
Period                                  
0   83.04   83.02   82.98   82.70   82.70   82.67   0.0     0.0     2.0
1   83.04   83.02   81.28   82.71   82.69   79.61   3.0     5.0     3.0
```

**EDIT**

To simply swap the levels, you can use `.swaplevel()`:

```
df_new = df.pivot_table(values=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns='Date', index='Period')

df_new.columns = df_new.columns.swaplevel()

#Output

Date     1012019    2012019 3012019 1012019 2012019 3012019 1012019 2012019 3012019
         A          A       A       B       B       B       C       C       C
Period                                  
0        83.04      83.02   82.98   82.70   82.70   82.67   0.0     0.0     2.0
1        83.04      83.02   81.28   82.71   82.69   79.61   3.0     5.0     3.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to keep my 'A', 'B', 'C' in the dataframe (like keep it just below the column header)?

Comment: Yes we can, check edit I made to original post. @SunnyBoiz

Comment: Thank you! :) Learnt about swaplevel() today!

Answer (score 0):

One further solution:

```
df['Period'] = df.groupby('Date').cumcount()
df.set_index(['Period', 'Date']).unstack()
```